# Why can I not convert an object to int in Python and how do I check the troublesome data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run the code:

```
df["columnname"].astype(int)
```

And it does not convert my datatype to int.  Instead, it's still listed as an object.  There are a lot of rows in the column, but I quickly did a sort in Excel and they were all numbers.  Integers in fact.  Why does Python think there's a string in there, when there is not.  I've tried float as well and stubbornly (just to make sure there's not a non-int in there) and it still thinks it's a string.

Assuming Excel is wrong, how do I check exactly which value cannot be converted to an int, and is causing the problem.

Comment: Might be a stupid point but, did you assign it back to your df?

Comment: No, I think you are right.  I am doing stuff in Jupyter but this totally makes sense as there's another line after it that converts another column into ints, and it works.  I'll try that now.

Comment: Thing is, I stopped re-assigning dfs when I tried to reassign  ```df = df.rename()``` and that caused an error... Guess I learned a bad habit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to explicity tell python to change the datatype as follows:

```
df["columnname"] = df["columnname"].astype(int)
```